# SQL - Delete from Multiple Tables (with FK)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to delete data from three tables.
I have an AccountId which I will set, then I want to delete the associated data.

The Id in Appointment.Id and AppointmentExtension.Id is the same value (GUID)

```
Table:Appointment
---------------------

 - Id 
 - Name  
 - AccountId

Table: AppointmentExtension
----------------------

 - Id
 - Settings

Table:SettingItems
---------------------

 - Id
 - AppointmentExtensionId(FK)
```

So essentially I want to set the parameter `@accountId. = "ABCD"`
and delete all the records.

Note that I have a FK on `SettingItems.AppointmentExtensionId = AppointmentExtension.Id`,
Assume I need to delete all the items in table `SettingItems` before deleting the other two due to the FK?

An example of how to do this would be great?

Answer (score 0):

you need tot start from the child in order as below:

```
delete from SettingItems
where AppointmentExtensionId in ( select Id from AppointmentExtension)

delete from AppointmentExtension where id in ( select id from  Appointment where @AccountId = accountId

delete from Appointment where @AccountId = accountId
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `delete from join`

```
delete si
from SettingItems si 
join Appointment a on si.AppointmentExtensionId = a.id
     and a.AccountId = @accountId;

delete ae
from AppointmentExtension ae 
join Appointment a on ae.id = a.id
     and a.AccountId = @accountId;
```